# Meaning of "it would seem that strategy being followed is to protect defer and delay the case of luis posada"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I think the meaning is ambiguous.

> "it would seem that strategy being followed is to protect defer and delay the case of luis posada"

I don't know if it's referring to the purpose of strategy or just the action of protecting

Also why is it used 'to protect' instead of 'protecting'?

Comment: "Protact" is not an English word. Do you mean "protect?"

Comment: "protact" isn't a word. What is the source of that phrase?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty TypeIA yes i thought it existed

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question because you have not provided a link or even a complete sentence. it may refer to the purpose or to the means; determining which requires at least a complete sentence and probably requires context.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow this is  complete sentence "it would seem that strategy being followed is to protect, defer and delay the case of luis posada"

Comment: You originally wrote 'protact'. Since the question edit I suggest the word [**protract**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/protract) – Prolong. So the sentence becomes "it would seem that strategy being followed is to protract, defer and delay the case of Luis Posada." In other words, make it take as long as possible.

Comment: @LautdeCarfeg It is a complete sentence after it was edited.

Comment: @LautdeCarfeg Can you please confirm which word you want to use: "protect" or "protract"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sentence is

> The strategy is to protract, defer, and delay the case of Luis Posada

then it is describing means rather than purpose. The purpose may be stated elsewhere. So the sentence is not ambiguous. It may, however, describe a foolish strategy. That depends on the purpose.

Comment: Why is it not used 'protecting' instead of 'to protact'?

Comment: Because “protect” has nothing in common with “defer” and “delay” whereas “protract,” “defer,” and “delay” are synonyms. And “protact” is not a valid English word.

Comment: Oops i meant "protacting" my question was why is it used an infinitive instead of the gerund form.

Comment: You keep misspelling "protract," which means to "drag out" and is based on a Latin root "trahere" with a passive participle "tractus." https://www.etymonline.com/word/protract The reason that we do not use a participle here is that this is an infinitive of means: it says what the strategy consists of.